# Force closing an oracle connection in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a report window which shows the results returned from a potentially long running oracle stored procedure. My problem is when the user closes the window the connection to oracle remains open and the potentially long running report doesn't get cancelled.

The only way to close the open connection is for either the DBAs to kill them manually or for the user to exit the entire application.

I've tried calling `Close` on the connection from a different thread, but this seems to continuously block. I also tried rolling back a transaction, but this exhibits the same problem.

I'm worried that the only solution will be to run the query in a different process (or maybe app domain?).

It's likely that I'm missing something obvious, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**PLEASE READ**

This question is not about wrapping my connection in a `using` statement. It is about how to *force an oracle connection that is executing a query to close*.

Example:

- Start a thread running a query
- Stash the connection object somewhere
- Call close on the connection object

  ```
  public void Go()
  {
      OracleConnection connection;
      var queryThread = new Thread(
          () =>
              {
                  using (connection = OpenOracleConnection())
                  {
                      // execute stored proc that takes 45 mins
                      // raise an event with the data set we load
                  }
              });

      Thread.Sleep(3000); // give it time to be useless

      var closeThread = new Thread(
          () =>
              {
                  connection.Close();
              });
      closeThread.Start();
  }
  ```

The problem is that this doesn't close the connection, instead the call to connection.Close() blocks waiting for the procedure to execute.

Comment: Which ADO.NET Oracle provider are you using ? (The Microsoft provided one doesn't support asynchronous processing, so if it's that one, you might need to write code to connect in another connection and kill the offending process).

Comment: It's the Oracle.DataAccess provider that comes with 11.2.0.

Comment: Not a well asked question.  Obviously you'll have to abort the query first.  You won't get an answer until you explain how you set this train wreck in motion, "report window" is meaningless.  Post code.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback. While posting my code would be useful, it would blind anyone who looked at it. That I'm running my oracle procedure from a different thread is incidental, but I'll try to demonstrate my code.

Comment: @Hans Passant, obviously I'll have to abort the query. How would I obviously abort the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, I can't see anything in the API to abort / cancel an ongoing query . Technically it should be possible, with a second session with full privileges, to identify the session you want to abort and issue the kill session command on that session. I would expect your original session to bail out with some kind of exception, but I've never tried it out.

[Here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/KillingOracleSessions.php) it is explained how to kill a session.

[Here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_how_to_display_session_id_sid.htm) it is answered how to get the session id. You could find that one out before starting the long running query, then it should be pretty easy to kill exactly that session from a second connection.

Let us know if it works ;)

Comment: Good idea, I'll run this past the DBAs, see if they'll go for it. I think it'd mean giving the calling credentials the ability to alter system, which might not fly.

Comment: you can use a different user to do the kill session, doesn't have to be the same account...

Comment: I've whipped this up and it works great, this pointed me in the right direction.  I'm doing `select sid, serial# from v$session where audsid = sys_context('userenv','sessionid')` followed by an `alter system kill session(sid,session) immediate` if the user needs to abort the query.

Comment: I run into ORA-00028 in 0.1% of the cases. I am running thousands of queries on IIS and few times a day have this `ORA-00028: your session has been killed`

Answer (score 1):

To see what/who is blocking who:

```
select s1.username || '@' || s1.machine
   || ' ( SID=' || s1.sid || ' )  is blocking '
   || s2.username || '@' || s2.machine || ' ( SID=' || s2.sid || ' ) ' AS status
   from v$lock l1, v$session s1, v$lock l2, v$session s2
   where s1.sid=l1.sid and s2.sid=l2.sid
   and l1.BLOCK=1 and l2.request > 0
   and l1.id1 = l2.id1
   and l2.id2 = l2.id2;
```

Answer (score 0):

As with any provider in .NET you can call `Dispose`

```
using(var conn = /* your connection */) {
    // do your stuff

    conn.Close();
} // this will automatically call .Dispose()
```

So that is all you need to do.

Comment: How can I call close or dispose when the thread that's opened the connection and is currently executing the query is blocked for 45 minutes?

Comment: I must admit that my experience with an Oracle database is limited but I can tell you that its not normal for a query to be blocked for 45 minutes.  It would help if you posted how you are opening the connection, you should be able to close the connection, you not being able to means its your code.

Comment: Not all the queries take 45 minutes, for the majority they execute within seconds, but this requires people to supply parameters to reduce the result set, unfortunately they don't always supply the right ones.

Comment: Oh and to be clear, if you run the same query manually in TOAD it also takes 45 minutes, which further indicates that it's nothing to do with the existing code.