# materialized views on external database fail to refresh at specified time - SQL*Net more data from dblink

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

We use a web-based service that runs on Oracle.  They are strict about only allowing SELECT-only ODBC access.  Some of the reporting that we do isn't well accounted for by the views that the company provisions, so we set up a db_link using the express edition of Oracle 11g and rewrote some of the more important queries as materialized views, using the refresh: specify settings to re-run the queries hourly, which is current enough for our purposes. All good so far.

I noticed that some of the MVs would stop refreshing, with no real pattern behind it.  Investigating further it looks from time to time the external database (the one that we're connected to via db_link) doesn't complete the query from time to time, and the refresh process sits patiently waiting on the event 'SQL*Net more data from dblink' indefinitely.

Here's the query I ran to get data about the stuck refresh sessions and the three sessions that seem to be stuck refresh statements:

```
select a.username, a.osuser, a.sid, a.serial#, b.spid, a.seconds_in_wait, 
       a.event, a.state, a.wait_class
from v$session a, v$process b
where a.paddr = b.addr
and a.seconds_in_wait > 500 and a.username is not null;

USERNAME    OSUSER  SID SERIAL# SPID    SECONDS_IN_WAIT EVENT                         STATE   WAIT_CLASS
KIPP_NWK    SYSTEM  27  7904    2704    161991          SQL*Net more data from dblink WAITING Network
KIPP_NWK    SYSTEM  35  2469    3880    139489          SQL*Net more data from dblink WAITING Network
KIPP_NWK    SYSTEM  37  6051    1408    40860           SQL*Net more data from dblink WAITING Network
```

I think my question is thus 'any suggestions about a script that will periodically (say, hourly) scan for stuck sessions of event type 'more data from dblink' and terminate them?'  The desired behavior for me is that this refresh is more resilient -- if it times out, I'd like it to start over and try, try again...

I don't think that figuring out why the external db stops executing these queries is going to be all that fruitful -- the provider provides the select privileges but is pretty clear about not wanting to support/troubleshoot any issues that arise.

I read about setting idle_time and changing the set SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME in sqlnet.ora file - but I don't get the sense that's the right approach as the connections aren't idle, they're active but waiting indefinitely, as well as the complicating factor that these sessions are initiated by the database itself.

How do I make this refresh more resilient/automatically kill these long-waiting refreshes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tbone, thanks for the dbms_scheduler resources.  What I ended up doing was building a scheduled job that looks for the stuck dblink refreshes and terminates those.  It seems to be working nicely.

I created this stored procedure that kills jobs that have been waiting for 10 minutes on SQL*Net more data from dblink:

```
create or replace procedure kill_stuck_refresh
as
begin     
    for x in (  
            select username, osuser, sid, serial#, seconds_in_wait, 
            event, state, wait_class
            from v$session
            where username is not null 
                  and seconds_in_wait > 600 
                  and event = 'SQL*Net more data from dblink'  
        ) loop  
        execute immediate 'alter system disconnect session '''|| x.sid  
                     || ',' || x.serial# || ''' immediate';
        dbms_output.put_line( 'Alter session done' );             
    end loop;  
end;
```

and then this dbms job that regularly runs the stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(job_name        => 'kill_stuck_refresh_jobs',
                          job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                          job_action      => 'kill_stuck_refresh',
                          start_date      => sysdate,
                          repeat_interval => 'freq=minutely; interval=15',
                          end_date        => NULL,
                          enabled         => TRUE,
                          comments        => 'calls kill_stuck_refresh every 15 minutes');
END;
/
```

this how-to was helpful, even though it doesn't use the new syntax for scheduled jobs: http://baurdotnet.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/oracle-job-session-killer/

Comment: glad you found a solution that works for you.  Still, for me, killing the sessions isn't really solving the issue of why these refreshes are not completing in the time you specify (15 min?).  You may also want to verify that there are no blocking sessions preventing the view from refreshing (see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936316/force-closing-an-oracle-connection-in-c/4937964#4937964 )

Comment: @Andrew will the job reschedule automatically when you kill them?

Comment: @Kitex it will - the job runs at its normal time.

Comment: @tbone you are right here and ultimately all of this ended up getting re-worked.  I'm not an expert on the inner workings of the shared global area, but MVs that used a dblink generate enormous amounts of redo.  This caused performance problems elsewhere.  The MVs that used dblinks have been rewritten as custom PL/SQL refresh jobs.  For instance, http://bit.ly/MWQU3K became http://bit.ly/OItcnQ.  If anyone else finds this, I'd avoid MVs that touch a dblink if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Don't connect through a dblink just to execute a refresh on a mat view on a remote Oracle instance.  Just setup a scheduler job to launch the refresh on the same instance as the view.

You shouldn't need to open a connection and wait for a refresh to complete.  This is more of an automated admin job, than something that an external client should launch and baby-sit.  If you need to check its status, you can check dba_scheduler_jobs, dba_scheduler_job_log, dba_scheduler_run_details, all_scheduler_running_jobs, etc. (more than this, but these will tell you a lot).

See [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/Scheduler10g.php) for some good examples.  Other enhancements if you're on 11g.

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough -- the MV is not "on a remote Oracle instance" - it's local. So there are already dbms_refresh jobs created by the MV to refresh these tables -- the problem is that sometimes they don't complete (and they hang forever).

Comment: @Andrew: I know you have the refresh job already setup, but you seem to be launching the refresh from a client over dblink, correct?  If so, I'm suggesting that you setup a Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER job to launch the refresh on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Recently we also faced the same issue with our materialized view complete refresh process. The issue was minimized by further optimizing the network time required for refresh (from around 25 minutes to around 2 minutes; although the end-to-end refresh still took around 10 minutes). Here is what we did:

Assuming that your data source query is already optimized, you may further reduce the refresh time as described below:

**Step 1)** Create materialized view in NOLOGGING mode (with no indexes and no auto refresh schedule) on machine where original materialized view exists

**Step 2)** Recreate the original materialized view in LOGGING mode with the above materialized view as the local data source (with required indexes and no auto refresh schedule)

**Step 3)** Create a refresh procedure that performs the following tasks:

1- refresh the materialized view created in NOLOGGING mode

2- verify the data integrity between the the local and remote data source

3- if verified then do the complete refresh of the materialized view (created in LOGGED mode)

I am no expert so please correct me if any of my assumptions are incorrect. I have documented this process on my blog post [Oracle Materialized View Complete Refresh over Database Link](https://moizmuhammad.wordpress.com/2015/10/25/oracle-materialized-view-complete-refresh-over-database-link-dblink/)

Disclaimer: This is my personal blog